# Will Web Service / MySQL run in iOs Simulator

Tags: mysql, ios, json, xcode4

I'm coding an app in XCode4, and am approaching a part of the development in which I use web services to connect to a MySQL database to both pull current and write new user account information.

Just wondering if this will work in the iOS Simulator that comes with the XCode bundle?

Comment: I don't know, but I imagine it would be a pretty lousy simulator if Web services wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need an answer for this question, as you have it right there in the same question.

I really think you should **take home the following**:

1. A *web-service* is an interface to a (possibly) remote entity that will answer to you with data/calculations etc.
2. There are two sides to a web-service: (1) the server side which is the real web-service, and (2) the client side which are the web-service libraries that you use to connect and use/get data from
3. A web-service to a MySQL database will **encapsulate/hide** the database from you. This is usually so that you don't need to deal with the query language/data conversion/relationships/etc. Keep in mind that there's no MySQL over web-services (out-of-the-box), so someone **has to connect those two for you**.
4. A MySQL server can run on your computer, on a virtual machine on your computer or on a remote computer.
5. The web service can run on the same places, but **not necessarily on the same place**
6. That said the iOS Simulator doesn't need to run the web-service **or** the MySQL server, It only needs to connect to them. As such they may be wherever, you just need to be able to connect to them.

Comment: Nice job explaining how this works.

Comment: @Pekka웃: It means a lot coming from you, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The simulator is able to make HTTP(S) requests, so of course web services would work.